# How to get notified when Microsoft Graph beta version changed or released?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to be notified about Microsoft Graph beta version updates.
How do I get notified when Microsoft Graph beta version changed or released?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the [changelog](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/changelog/) web site which contains a link to a RSS feed.

```
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/changelog/rss
```

When you subscribe to the RSS feed you should be able to receive notifications about changes.